# Is there a specific reason why Calculated column will have Crawled property while it will not have Managed Property

Tags: 2013, search, managed-property, crawled-property, search-schema

I have a calculated column (inside my sharepoint 2013 on-premises), which is based on other fields of type currency as follow:-

[image]

now i want to show this calculated field inside a content search web part. but i did not find any managed property representing this column. so i went to Central Admin >> Search service >> Search Schema >> Crawled Property. and i find the related item as follow:-

[image]

but there is not any managed property for this field. although i define the calculated column as site column... so can anyone advice on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, in 2013 calculated columns were not automatically promoted. (This feature was removed in 2016 & SPO.) All you need to do, since you have central admin access, is create your own Managed Property for the field.

Comment: ok i got your point. so i need to create a new managed property and link it with the related crawled property.. so sharepoint 2013 still support this for calculated columns,, but does not provide it by defualt, as it do for other column types (single text, number, date, etc..)??

Comment: now i create a new managed property for the calculated column, but when i display the managed property inside my content search web part it got rendered something as follow `float;#8230.44000000000 `.. so is there a way to fix this an to show only the actual value `8230.44`

Comment: You can alter the display template for split on `;#' and round to two decimals using JavaScript.